# Ruby on Rails: current_page? problem when using actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm now implementing navigation tabs for my Rails application.
I would like to generate different CSS and html for current tab (add id="current" and do not
link the title) - basic stuff.

I found the function: **current_page?** but unfortunately it doesn't work in a way i would expect:

When I call: current_page?(:controller => "bank_account") it returns true for /bank_account but not for /bank_account/soem_action

Is there a way to force **current_page?** to return true in this case? So when I don't specify the action it should return true for all the actions of the given controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this answered question:

[link_to_unless_current fails when processing forms with error messages in it with restfull routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104197/linktounlesscurrent-fails-when-processing-forms-with-error-messages-in-it-with)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
controller.controller_name
```

to retrieve the controllers name in a view.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case as I can have the urls like:
- /admin/users (where users is controller and /admin is just a subdir)
- /users

For both cases the controller name is users - current_page? works well but fails when I add actions. 

It looks like i will have to reimplement the current_page? to suit my needs.

Comment: But controller.controller_name will return users in this case. Maybe I don't get it.

Comment: What about params[:controller], IIRC that returns the controller name along with the "admin" namespace: params[:controller] == "admin/users"

Answer (score 0):

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3279194). Usage instructions in article [A Better Way to Add a ‘selected’ Class to Links in Rails](http://viget.com/extend/rails-selected-nav-link-helper). Linked to from [question Best way to add “current” class to nav in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705898/best-way-to-add-current-class-to-nav-in-rails-3).