# User Helper Method for Current Navigation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, navigation, helper, link-to

I have the following navigation HTML:

```
<nav class="col9">
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to find a way to dynamically add the class of "current" to the relevant list item (if we are on the page).

I have the following code in my **application_helper.rb**:

```
def menu_link(name, options = {}, html_options = {})
        html_options.merge!({ :class => 'current'}) if current_page?(options)
        link_to name, options, html_options
    end
```

However, this adds the class of current to the anchor tag instead of the list item. Would anyone be able to assist me in modifying this?

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to add "current" class to nav in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705898/best-way-to-add-current-class-to-nav-in-rails-3)