# Rails: set default 'current' css class for navigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's a problem after using the solution here 
[Best way to add "current" class to nav in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705898/best-way-to-add-current-class-to-nav-in-rails-3)

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path)
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'current' : ''
  content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
    link_to link_text, link_path
  end
end
```

For example, I have `localhost/action1`, and `localhost/action2`, each with a nav button.
It works great when user is in either page. In this situation, one of the button would have a 'current' css class.

But, if I set `root_path` to one of them, let's say is the `/action1`, so when user visit `localhost`, the button for `action1` won't have a `current` class

How can I solve add the missing `current` css class when setting it as the `root_path`?

Comment: Hm, why so difficult comparison? Maybe it would be easier to compare the request.path to link path (if you use built-in methods to get path for link)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the router itself to give you the `controller` and the `action` for the current path and just compare it to the current values from `params`.

```
def nav_link(text, path)
  recognized = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)

  klass = "current" if recognized[:controller] == params[:controller] &&
    recognized[:action] == params[:action]

  content_tag(:li, class: klass) do
    link_to(text, path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to recognize queries like `localhost/posts?number=7`. Possiblely `recognized[:number]`?

Comment: @cqcn1991 `localhost/posts?number=7` and `localhost/posts` are identical as far as the router is concerned. If you want to take the query parameters into account, you need to fetch and switch on them yourself (`request.query_parameters` gives you `{"number"=>"7"}`).

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to highlight your nav menu the following way - I am pretty sure this works irrespective setting the root path:

```
<ul>
  <li class="<%= "current" if params[:controller] == "home" %>">Home</li>
  <li class="<%= "current" if params[:controller] == "action1" %>">Action 1</li>
  <li class="<%= "current" if params[:controller] == "action2" %>">Action 2</li>
</ul>
```

You may wish to replace

```
params[:controller]
```

with

```
params[:action]
```

depending on the level you wish to highlight. I have used this setup in a recent project and it worked for me. Good luck !